# How can I unlist a nested list and keep the names of the sublist (as is) and the names of the elements?

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have a nested list with 3 levels:

1. length of string (I don't care about that when all is done, it's just for the ordering of the lists)
2. Category (I want to keep this in the output)
3. Elements (strings I also want to keep)

I want to unlist/flatten this construct to get a character vector with the order in the list and all elements should be named:

"Category""_""Element"

I cannot get this done. My problem is that either level 2 is not kept as a name or that it keeps the index as well so I get wrong names (e.g. Dog, Dog1, Dog2, Dog3 instead of Dog).

I have tried first purrr::flatten -> the resulting list looks good (I think).

Then I tried unlist of the flattened output to get all these items into a character vector and this is, where it gets me.

I receive names of the elements like:

TCRBV11-031 TCRBV11-032 TCRBV11-033

but they should all be TCRBV11-03

How can I keep the name of the sublist and combine it with the element. Preferably with a "_" in-between?

Edit: dput of an example list:

```
list(`11` = list(`TCRBV06-01` = "CAIDRSYEQYF", `TCRBV29-01` = "CSADRKETQYF"), 
    `12` = list(`TCRBV05-06` = "CASSRPNTEAFF", `TCRBV06-01` = "CASGHKNTEAFF", 
        `TCRBV07-03` = "CASSLRLHEQYF"), `13` = list(`TCRBV02-01` = "CASQGIVGYEQYF", 
        `TCRBV05-01` = "CASTGSLNTEAFF", `TCRBV06-04` = "CASSLGKNTEAFF", 
        `TCRBV07-03` = "CASSLTEGGGYTF", `TCRBV07-08` = "CASSPDTNTEAFF", 
        `TCRBV07-09` = "CASSPDRDTEAFF", `TCRBV10-03` = "CAISMISNQPQHF", 
        `TCRBV18-01` = "CASSPPETYEQYF", `TCRBV19-01` = "CASSIGGSTEAFF", 
        `TCRBV20-01` = c("CSAMAYRADGYTF", "CSAREAQAETQYF", "CSAITSRVDGYTF"
        ), `TCRBV27-01` = "CASSFPGGYGYTF"), `14` = list(`TCRBV05-06` = "CASSLVGASYEQYF", 
        `TCRBV06-01` = c("CASRQGQENQPQHF", "CASRRQGEGTEAFF"), 
        `TCRBV07-09` = "CASSPGVSGNTIYF", `TCRBV10-02` = "CASSPAEGGYEQYF", 
        `TCRBV13-01` = "CASSLGQGVYEQYF", `TCRBV24-01` = "CATRSTGANTEAFF"), 
    `15` = list(`TCRBV02-01` = "CASSDVLAGGPEQYF", `TCRBV04-01` = "CASSQDPAGGRKLFF", 
        `TCRBV04-03` = "CASSQDSTALYGYTF", `TCRBV05-01` = "CASSFEDRGAGGYTF", 
        `TCRBV05-04` = c("CASGLTGEGNTEAFF", "CASSPVSSRTDTQYF"
        ), `TCRBV06-04` = "CASSDSSSGYNEQFF", `TCRBV07-09` = "CASSPTSGVGSEQFF", 
        `TCRBV10-03` = "CAISGGGGSTNIQYF", `TCRBV11-03` = "CASSDETGAGYEQFF", 
        `TCRBV13-01` = "CASSSSTALYNEQFF", `TCRBV18-01` = "CASSPLAGGSNEQYF", 
        `TCRBV25-01` = "CASSEDRGLDQPQHF", `TCRBV28-01` = "CASSPVAGGHYEQYF", 
        `TCRBV30-01` = "CAWSWGGGLGEKLFF"), `16` = list(`TCRBV04-01` = "CASSQVVIPPGEKLFF", 
        `TCRBV14-01` = "CASSQPGLLGTDTQYF", `TCRBV15-01` = "CATSRWGTGELTEAFF", 
        `TCRBV19-01` = "CASSIGTADIYNEQFF", `TCRBV20-01` = "CSARGQTSGFTYEQYF"), 
    `17` = list(`TCRBV04-01` = "CASSQDPRTASYNEQFF", `TCRBV04-02` = "CASSQDLETSGDDIQYF", 
        `TCRBV25-01` = "CASSEYTTGEVTDTQYF"), `18` = list(`TCRBV12-05` = "CASGLVGGVLSGANVLTF"), 
    `19` = list(`TCRBV04-03` = "CASSQDPKGGLLNTGELFF"))
```

Comment: Please provide an example of such a list. You can do so by posting the output of `dput(mylist)`.

Comment: @Cettt I provided an example, though the problem actually arises when there are more than 1 element in one sublist and you cannot really see it in this output.